# What does the phrase "es reut mich" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase

I was reading a book and came across the phrase "es reut mich". I am not familiar with the conjugated word of "reut". I understand the phrase to mean "it pains me," but what does it really mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means "to regret/to feel remorse".

Note that "reuen" is not used in spoken or written language anymore. Nowadays you would use "(etw.) bereuen".

Comment: Still used: https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=reut+dich%2Creut+mich%2Creut+ihn%2Creut+sie%2Creut+uns%2C&year_start=1920&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Creut%20dich%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creut%20mich%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creut%20ihn%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creut%20sie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creut%20uns%3B%2Cc0

Comment: It may still be used occasionally, but it has a distinctly oldfashioned touch to it. You might encounter it when listening to funeral speaches, preachers in church etc.

Comment: Thank you. The book I was reading is written in older fashioned language. Also +1 for giving the equivalent word for today's usage.

Comment: I heard it said some times (admittedly from older generations) in switzerland. I cannot say, though, if it is generally more common there or if it is considered oldfashioned there, too.

Comment: +1 for Switzerland. I remember a Swiss lady who ordered a tea in a café, and got a teabag and a cup of hot water which was filled only halfway, and she argued: "Reut Sie das Wasser?"